# Sqlite with EF6 doesn't work when deployed on server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have been developing a web application that using Sqlite to store some data. When I deploy it to the server I get the error message below. The path to the file in the connection string is correct and it is working properly on my development machine. What can be wrong?

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices,
>   System.Data.SQLite.EF6' registered in the application config file for
>   the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite' could
>   not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and
>   that the assembly is available to the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information

Comment: Well the error is quite self-explanatory, isn't it ?

Comment: @Fabjan if it was, I would not ask that question. The file is there, the web.config file is the same as in dev and the path to the file has been changed accordingly. Any ideas?

Comment: @Midas Make sure to install the SQLite provider on the deployment server.

Comment: @EBrown: Ah do you mean the precompiled binaries? https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki I forgot those, but now I get a BadImageFormatException. I picked the 4.6 binaries, since my project is for 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. When I setup Sqlite in my development machine I used an installer that installed (except from the Dll's) designer tools for Visual Studio. When deploying to the server all the required DLLs were not included. Sqlite has unmanaged libraries that target x86 or x64 systems. Those are installed to the development machine, but are not available in your project. When you do a so called XCOPY-deployment on the server, the unmanaged providers will not be available. You need to download them from the following link: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and include them in you bin-folder. That is not enough though.

The .NET projects are by default set to Any CPU. You need to target your application to run x86 or x64 (my option) depending on the server operating system (32bits or 64). Only then the Sqlite provider will load.